# Unable to get the last inserted data from sqlite table

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

In my application I need to get the data from the last inserted into table. What I have done is this

```
 NSString *query  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM PHONEBOOK ORDER BY NAME DESC LIMIT 1;"];

    //  NSLog(@"query : %@",query);

    BOOL recordExist = [self recordExistOrNot:query];

    if (!recordExist) {

        // save data if no record exists
    }




    -(BOOL)recordExistOrNot:(NSString *)query{

BOOL recordExist=NO;

sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &myDatabase) == SQLITE_OK) {




    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDatabase, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            recordExist=YES;

            NSString *Name = [[NSString alloc]
                                 initWithUTF8String:
                                 (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(
                                                                    statement, 0)];
            NSString *PhoneNumber = [[NSString alloc]
                                     initWithUTF8String:
                                     (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(
                                                                        statement, 1)];

            //here i need to get the Name and number from the last inserted data
            NSLog(@"version is %@, type is %@",Name ,PhoneNumber);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"%s,",sqlite3_errmsg(myDatabase));
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(myDatabase);
    }

}
return recordExist;
```

}

The problem is I'm not getting the last inserted data. I am getting  the data from other rows ( i am not sure whether it is from top row or any other) .

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These things are called "rows", not "columns". And `ORDER BY Name DESC` returns the row with the name that is last in alphabetic order.

Comment: Note that http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html has some fairly good documentation (though it's bit fragmented).  And there are dozens of SQL tutorials online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If doing this immediately after inserting the row, you can use the SQLite C function [`sqlite3_last_insert_rowid()`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) to get the `rowid` for the last inserted row. You can also use the `last_insert_rowid()` SQL function:

```
SELECT * FROM PHONEBOOK WHERE ROWID = last_insert_rowid()
```

Note, you probably have to keep the SQLite database open to do this (but you shouldn't be opening and closing the database for every SQL statement, anyway).

If you're doing this at some later date (e.g. the user terminates the app, comes back to it tomorrow, and wants to see the last inserted record), then you have to rely upon your own database model to handle that. For example, I frequently will have create/modify/delete timestamps in my table that I update every time I `INSERT` or `UPDATE` the row, and you can then sort based upon those values.

Comment: Did you close and reopen the database between the insertion of the record and the attempt to use this function? That would result in the loss of the rowid. Make sure you keep the database open.

Comment: i am not doing this immediately after inserting the row. Can I get the row id after inserting the row and later use this id to get the data?

Comment: i am now getting the row id.  I used this.       if (sqlite3_step(insertStatement )== SQLITE_DONE) {
            
            NSLog(@"Contact sucessfully saved : new item id is %lld",sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(db));
        }

Comment: Yep, that's how to do it.